# When picking up dead opponent weapons do you get their perks as well?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Playing COD:BO on PS3. If you pick up a weapon off the ground, do you also get their perks from the dead opponent who had the weapon ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you do not. Picking up an opponent's weapon is not like the kits in Battlefield 2, where you take all of their weapons and abilities. In Call of Duty you just swap your weapon for their weapon, nothing else changes. You can use this to your advantage by swapping your secondary weapon (usually a pistol) for an assault rifle or smg etc.

Answer (score 7):

No perks, but if the opponent had warlord, then you have a weapon with two attachments without having to choose the perk.

Comment: hey.. that's a great tip. I hadn't considered that.

Comment: Yeah... nothing beats getting an assault rifle with dual attachments while you have the sleight of hand perk